# If $P$ is a transition Markov matrix of a Marcov chain discrete, then $P^{n}$ a transition Markov matrix?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have a doubt that I want someone to help me answer, I ask is the following:

**If  $P$ is a transition Markov matrix of a Marcov chain discrete, then  $P^{n}$ a transition Markov matrix ?.**

Comment: *Hint* : $Pe = e$ $\implies$ $P^ne=e$

Comment: Yes. From the probabilistic point of view it should be clear: $(P^n)_{ij}$ is the probability to go from $i$ to $j$ in $n$ steps of the chain with transition matrix $P$ (assuming the row-stochastic convention). From the linear algebraic point of view, it is just a calculation (multiply $P^n$ by the column vector of all $1$s).